# "Умная" компиляция python

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, сборка, pyinstaller

Собираю проект с помощью pyinstaller. Сам проект - максимально простецкий автокликер, который только можно придумать: поле для ввода текста (задержка), 2 радиокнопочки "ЛКМ" или "ПКМ" и 2 кнопки сарт/стоп. Интерфейс на QT. При сборке в единый exe-шник его вес получается аж 30 мегабайт! Я так понимаю, pyinstaller полностью запаковывет туда QT. Собственно, теперь основной вопрос: можно ли заставить pyinstaller убрать из exe-шника все лишние функции, которые там просто не используются? Либо же есть ли сторонние утилиты, которые могут сделать подобное?

Comment: а как у тебя импорт написан ?

Comment: Некоторые советы можно почитать здесь  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60275109/pyinstaller-excluding-submodules-while-compiling  и здесь  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49045142/reduce-size-of-pyqt5-html-viewer-application-build-with-pyinstaller

Answer (score 0):

Это нормально, что такой вес -- там действительно порой весьма сложные связи внутри. Я бы рекомендовал Вам на данном этапе вместо этого воспользоваться каким-нибудь популярным [упаковщиком исполняемых файлов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2) и ваша проблема будет решена без лишних хлопот.